# IEEE-754: cardinality of the set of rational numbers

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

What is the cardinality of the set of rational numbers, which have an exact representation in floating point format compatible with single-precision IEEE-754?

Comment: `2^32` minus the sizes of the ranges assigned to NaNs and infinities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2139095039 finite positive floats.
There are as many finite negative floats.

Do you want to include +0.0 and -0.0 as two items or as one? Depending on the answer the total is 2 * 2139095039 + 2 or 2 * 2139095039 + 1, that is, respectively, 4278190080 or 4278190079.

Source for the 2139095039 number:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  float f = FLT_MAX;
  unsigned int i;
  memcpy(&i, &f, 4);
  printf("%u\n", i);
}
```

Comment: @KevinL The representation of positive floats, interpreted as an integer, increases from the integer 0 for 0.0f to the integer 2139095039 for FLT_MAX. All the finite positive floats are between these two bounds, and each number between these two bounds is the representation of a unique float. This is a property of the IEEE 754 representation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format